Coroutine not starting in Unity WebSocket client after reconnect attempt
I'm working on a Unity project using WebSocketSharp to handle network connections. My script is supposed to reconnect to the server when the connection is lost or when there's an error. I'm using a coroutine to delay reconnection attempts. However, the coroutine doesn't seem to be starting, and I don't see the expected logs from ReconnectCoroutine().
Here's a simplified version of my code:
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using WebSocketSharp;

public class WebSocketClient : MonoBehaviour
{
    private WebSocket ws;
    public Configurations config;
    private int reconnectAttempt = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        ConnectToServer();
    }

    void ConnectToServer()
    {
        ws = new WebSocket(config.serverAddress);
        ws.OnOpen += (sender, e) => Debug.Log("Connected.");
        ws.OnError += (sender, e) => AttemptReconnect();
        ws.OnClose += (sender, e) => AttemptReconnect();
        ws.Connect();
    }

    void AttemptReconnect()
    {
        if (reconnectAttempt < config.maxReconnectAttempts)
        {
            reconnectAttempt++;
            Debug.Log($"Reconnect attempt {reconnectAttempt}/{config.maxReconnectAttempts}");
            StartCoroutine(ReconnectCoroutine());
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Max reconnect attempts reached.");
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator ReconnectCoroutine()
    {
        Debug.Log("Starting ReconnectCoroutine");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(config.reconnectDelay);
        Debug.Log("Reconnect Delay passed");
        ConnectToServer();
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        ws?.Close();
    }
}

In this setup:
ConnectToServer() is called on Start() and attempts to connect to a WebSocket server.
If there's an error or the connection closes, AttemptReconnect() is called.
This should log an attempt and start a coroutine to delay the next connection attempt.
The issue is that when AttemptReconnect() is called, I see the log for the reconnection attempt, but the coroutine (ReconnectCoroutine()) does not start, and thus the ConnectToServer() method is not called again after the delay.
The GameObject that this script is attached to is present and active, and the script is enabled.
Has anyone encountered this issue before or can spot what might be going wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The WebsocketSharp events are send on background threads and Coroutines are part of Monobehavior which needs to be run on the main thread.
you can use a main thread dispatcher to solve this problem, here is a link to another question which has an example: c# unity IEnumerator not working in eventhandler
